# unable to override mysql database using mysql chef coookbook

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, amazon-ec2, chef-infra, chef-recipe

I am newbie to the chef and its overall eco system, just has an experiment I trying to use mysql cookbook and trying to create a database and set username and password of the same. I am not able to figure out how to get this things done. I have set up my own chef-server on aws ec2 ubuntu instance. Kindly help me out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Checkout the [mysql_test](https://github.com/opscode-cookbooks/mysql/tree/master/test/cookbooks/mysql_test) cookbook. where it uses resource `mysql_database_user` provided from the [database](https://github.com/opscode-cookbooks/database) cookbook.

Here's the code sample:

```
include_recipe 'mysql::server'

mysql_connection = {:host => "localhost", :username => 'root',
                :password => node['mysql']['server_root_password']}

mysql_database node['mysql_test']['database'] do
  connection mysql_connection
  action :create
end

mysql_database_user node['mysql_test']['username'] do
  connection mysql_connection
  password node['mysql_test']['password']
  database_name node['mysql_test']['database']
  host 'localhost'
  privileges [:select,:update,:insert, :delete]
  action [:create, :grant]
end
```

Notice that you need to depend on the database cookbook and the mysql cookbook, and set the following node attributes:

- `default['mysql_test']['database']` - mysql database name
- `default['mysql_test']['username']` - mysql database user name
- `default['mysql_test']['password']` - mysql database user password

Comment: Hi,I am getting this error " Error executing action `install` on resource 'package[libmysqlclient-dev]'" . Unable to solve this.